# SQL- Collect all data into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to collect all return data into a variable using comma separated.

let say i have a select command like: `select * from #temptable`.
it's return:

```
Field1|Field2
-------------
Value1|Value2
```

> Expected Result: @testvariable hold the value: 'Value1','Value2'

On this table their may have 2 columns and i need to store all the return result into a single variable. We can easily collect a single value like: `select @var=column1 from #temptable.` But i need to store all.Here the problem is, the number of column can be vary. Mean, number of column and name of column generate from another query.So, i can't mention the field name.I need a dynamic way to do it. on this table only one row will be return. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without dynamic SQL using `XML`

```
DECLARE @xml XML = (SELECT * FROM #temptable FOR XML PATH(''))

SELECT stuff((SELECT ',' + node.value('.', 'varchar(100)')
              FROM   @xml.nodes('/*') AS T(node)
              FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
              , 1, 1, '');
```

This can probably be simplified by someone more adept at XML querying than me.

Comment: it's showing error:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@xml".

Comment: @riad - You may be on a CS collation then. Change `DECLARE @XML XML` to `DECLARE @xml XML`. Also what version are you on? You shouldn't get an incorrect syntax error if later than SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Sure you didn't lose anything such as brackets with the copy and paste? Or one other thing I've just noticed is that I have got a space between `type) .value`. Doesn't make any difference on 2008 but maybe does on 2005.

Comment: @riad - It should be `1, 1`. It is supposed to just trim the leading comma but is trimming too much.

Answer (score 0):

Since your column names are dynamic, so first you have to take the column names as comma separated in a variable and then can use `EXEC(`)

for example :-

```
  //making comma seperated column names from table B
     DECLARE @var varchar(1000)=SELECT SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT ',' + Colnames 
        FROM TABLEB
        ORDER BY Colnames 
        FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000)
  //Execute the sql statement   
        EXEC('select '+@var+' from tableA')
```

if you want to get the value returned after execution of sql statement then you can use 
[sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)